# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/picture.jpg"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I seem to have broken something in my rails 4.2 development environment.  I went to change an image on one of my apps pages with another image I placed in the same location as the original, `app/assets/images/picture.jpg` but the new image won't render, and I can see in the source that unlike other images it's not being fingerprinted and still shows as `picture.jpg` in the source.

I'm not sure how to debug this and I haven't been able to find a working solution online.  This is what prints in my rails server log:

```
Started GET "/images/picture.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-06-15 10:56:28 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/picture.jpg"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (19.6ms)
```

Thanks for any help!

Alxs

Comment: Try running `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Thanks @Pavan, that worked.  I don't recall having to do that just to add new images in development env. before.  Is that normal, or do I have a broken gem perhaps?

Comment: @Pavan, I have no idea what changed as I'm sure asset precompilation was working on the fly before, but I added `config.assets.compile = true` to the development environment variables now and it's working as expected again.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)